# imagick setimageformat zero size image string passed error - one of many errors - svg to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, svg, imagemagick

The problem is essentially: convert an svg to a pdf using image magick.

I take an image in a base64 format, do something to it, convert it to a bitmap, do something to is, store it inside an SVG string, write the svg to a file (doesn't have to be done, but wanted to make sure the svg was loading), then from here I need to convert the svg to a pdf.

```
//I just broke the string up over spaces for sake of readability
$svgStr = "<?xml version=1.0.' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xml:space='preserve'>
    <desc>
        Made by Shane
    </desc>
    <defs>
    </defs>
    <style>
    </style>
    <image width='500' height'auto' xlink:href'" . $path . $filename . $ext . "' />
</svg>";

file_put_contents($path . $svgFile . ".svg", $svgStr);

//Attempt 1 of many
$pdf = New Imagick($path . $svgFile . ".svg", "SVG");
$pdf->setImageFormat("PDF"); //This thows the "Can not process empty imagick object" error.
file_put_contents($path . $svgFile . ".pdf", $pdf);

//Attempt2 of many
$pdf = New Imagick();

//Throws an error here - can not process empty Imagick object...
//which brings me back to attempt 1... the idea in attempt 1 is to initialize
//the Imagick object with the svg format and data, then convert.
//Here the idea is to initialize it step by step

$pdf->setImageFormat("SVG");
//For readImageBlob(), I should be able to read the svg file or use the $svgStr.
$pdf->readImageBlob($svgStr);
$pdf->setImageFormat("PDF");
file_put_contents($path . $svgFile . ".pdf", $pdf);
```

I am running image magick 6.8.9-9. I can't upgrade, because I don't have sudo and it can't be accessed.

### Edit

I think this might be part of the problem - I get an error converting a .bmp to a pdf from the command line:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081695/error-during-converting-jpg-to-pdf

However, I don't know if the command line utilities operate in the same manner as the class wrapper does.

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur?

Comment: What's the point of the wrapper SVG that just has the contents as an image? Can't you just embed the image itself?

Comment: @RobertLongson , yes, I believe I could (provided that an error isn't thrown), but the SVG has css that is directly applied to the image. I could probably apply the same transformations to the image itself, but its much easier to simply use an SVG.

Comment: @fmw42 , I just updated the post to hopefully highlight the errors better, but essentially:
attempt 1: "Can not process empty imagick object" at `$pdf->setImageFormat("PDF");`
attempt 2: "Can not process empty imagick object" at `$pdf->setImageFormat("SVG");`
the second attempt's error was not initially that, but I altered the code (and the post to reflect the code). I would figure that something so 'simple' (if you will) wouldn't be so hard.

Comment: I am not an SVG expert. But perhaps your SVG file is not compatible with the ImageMagick SVG internal renderer. You can use that, the RSVG delegate if installed in ImageMagick or Inkscape as the best if installed on the system. Can you view your saved SVG file?  Can you open it in ImageMagick command line and convert to GIF or PNG?

Comment: I can view the SVG file. I can't convert it using the cmd line. I thought I had the RSVG delegate installed, but maybe I don't?... Ran the command rsvg on the cmd line and said its not installed... so... yah... Not like it matters too much, because I don't have admin privileges... You wouldn't happen to know how to take a bitmap and put an outline around every curve... I am aware that image magick has a canny edge detection algorithm in place, and I think I can use it in php, however even if I can, it is unlcear to me as to how to add the outline to the image... it needs to be super thin...